# "Module build failed: Operation on an invalid type" while using webpack

Tags: media, webpack

I am using webpack to hot replace my code base but when running it getting below mentioned error

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/less-loader!./combined.less
        Module build failed: Operation on an invalid type
        @\git\rebellion_tag\rebellion\bower_components\bootstrap\less\responsive-utilities.less (line 77, column 69)
     near lines:
         .visible-sm-block {
          @media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) and (max-width: @screen-sm-max) {
           display: block !important;
```

Comment: You should add the related .less file or the part around the mentioned line. An please learn how to format your text properly: there's a code block formatting option (you used inline formatting) and your descriptions should not be code formatted.

Comment: **Sry for not formatting it properly**                                                                 here is the code snippet of my less file                                                     '.visible-xs {
  @media (max-width: @screen-xs-max) {
    .responsive-visibility();
  }
}
}'